# Problems with an if statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a complex matrix with several rows per individual. I create a script where I summarize different variables per individual. In order to do that, I first create a list with the new summarized variables in it. In order to get some of these variables I need to introduce if clases like the following:

```
this_iids_roh <- dat[class,]
my_list<-c("Froh"=(sum(this_iids_roh$KB)/2881033),
         "chr1"= if (this_iids_roh$CHR==1) {(sum(this_iids_roh$KB)/247249.719)*100}, 
         "chr2"= if (this_iids_roh$CHR==2) {(sum(this_iids_roh$KB)/242193.529)*100}, 
         "chr3"= if (this_iids_roh$CHR==3) {(sum(this_iids_roh$KB)/198295.559)*100})
return(my_list)
```

However when I do run this script (this is just a small part) I only get the "Froh" and "chr1" variables. I tried several things but I'm not being able to get other variables after "chr1".
I hope you can help me!

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit your question!

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this question deserves negative votes?

Comment: First: I am **not** one of the downvoters. It seems to me that your question does not respect the conditions in [ask] and [mcve]. You didn't gave data to play with. You didn't gave the desired result. Your code isn't consistent (there is return(..) and a lonely `}` from a function definition).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of If condition outside you can directly use the condition to subset the data.

```
this_iids_roh <- NULL
this_iids_roh$CHR = rep(c(1,2,3),10)
this_iids_roh$KB  = runif(30)*100000
this_iids_roh = as.data.frame(this_iids_roh)
```

The way to do this is

```
my_list<-c("Froh"=(sum(this_iids_roh$KB)/2881033),
       "chr1"= {(sum(this_iids_roh$KB[this_iids_roh$CHR==1])/247249.719)*100}, 
       "chr2"= {(sum(this_iids_roh$KB[this_iids_roh$CHR==2])/242193.529)*100}, 
       "chr3"= {(sum(this_iids_roh$KB[this_iids_roh$CHR==3])/198295.559)*100})
> my_list
   Froh      chr1      chr2      chr3 
0.60958 203.99334 251.06703 324.65984
```

Hope this solves the problem. Note that the conditions are written inside the square brackets above.

---

alternativly

```
my_list<-c(Froh= sum(this_iids_roh$KB)/2881033,
           chr1= sum(this_iids_roh$KB[this_iids_roh$CHR==1])/2472.49719, 
           chr2= sum(this_iids_roh$KB[this_iids_roh$CHR==2])/2421.93529, 
           chr3= sum(this_iids_roh$KB[this_iids_roh$CHR==3])/1982.95559)
my_list
```

also fine with `with()`

```
my_list <- with(this_iids_roh, c(Froh= sum(KB)/2881033,
           chr1= sum(KB[CHR==1])/2472.49719, 
           chr2= sum(KB[CHR==2])/2421.93529, 
           chr3= sum(KB[CHR==3])/1982.95559))
my_list
```

Comment: What’s up with the curly braces? This is unconventional to say the least (curly braces in R are used to group *statements* separated by either semicolon or newline), and the code works just as well without them.

Comment: I was just trying to minimally edit his code. The curly braces can be removed without affecting the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, I tried without the curl braces and did not work, so I went back to the if. Now with those braces it worked